# $.post getting canceled in chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am calling a php file using `$.post`. From the server I am returning json response. When I open the server url directly in browser it returns successfully. But from js it is not working.
[image]
The link I am calling is this(`http://54.249.240.120/qcorner/login`).

```
<html>                                                                  
    <head>                                                                  
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>                                                                 
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="testID">
        <script type="text/javascript">                                         
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#testID").click(function() {
                    $.post('http://54.249.240.120/qcorner/login',function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    });
                });
            });
         </script>                                                               
     </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

I also tried in Firefox. In that I get 200 OK, but no response.

Why this is happening

Comment: I don't see any reason for it to be happening with the given html/js

Comment: But I showed you the response. :(

Comment: Chrome obviously isn't always showing the real response codes. Use a different method like curl to view the actual response codes being returned by the server, or review the access/error logs.

Comment: `http://theip` isn't needed, just use `'/qcorner/login'`, however it shouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: For me, the response is: `{"head":{"status":206,"message":"Only 0 fields received, required 2"},"body":""}`

Comment: @BitskiNet I also tried on Firefox, but no result. And I don't know about curl (and if anything other you are suggesting), please help.

Comment: What data are you posting to the URL?

Comment: @BotskoNet But I am not getting this response, this is what I expect to get.

Comment: @Kevin my server and client are on two different machine. And I am opening client as a sample local file on clien. So I think Ip is needed

Comment: @GigaWatt Nothing. I am posting no data.

Comment: Your ajax is sending an empty POST request to the url. When I do this via curl, I receive an `HTTP 206` error code. It has nothing to do with Chrome

Comment: @knoxxs that can cause an entirely differen't problem. YOur server doesn't appear to support CORS, so requesting data from it from another domain should fail with a same-origin error in the console.

Comment: @Kevin I made the body non-empty still getting the same result

Comment: @BotskoNet I changed the return status to 200, still getting the same result, and this is not the http response, its just a string I am returning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that it is a cross domain request the error being returned can be viewed by turning on the javascript console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://54.249.240.120/qcorner/login. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

You will need to make sure that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are set to allow this to happen or Chrome will cancel the request.

Comment: You can set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` on the remote server to allow cross domain request.  `*` will let all cross-domain traffic however you can set it to the requesting site instead if you wish to be more secure.

Comment: But what about FireFox, I just tried on localhost, still getting the same error. Why?

Comment: Firefox should obey the same thing - this isn't browser specific.  I recommend reading up on CORS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're running into a [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem. I'm guessing you're not accessing this page from `http://54.249.240.120/`, given that Chrome is showing it explicitly in the network tab (usually it doesn't do that if it's the same domain).

Long story short, you can't post via Javascript to another domain name. If you're accessing this at www.example.com, the browser won't recognize the IP address as the same domain name (even if the domain name resolves there). Easiest way, if you're in control of the whole situation, is just put that login code on the same domain as the code you're testing. In a local environment you can do this with your [hosts file, something like `54.249.240.120 www.example.com` to redirect example.com (replace with your own domain that you are accessing the test page from) to the IP address. This won't work for the public internet, however.

If you must POST to another domain via javascript, you'll need to look into implementing the CORS standard. [Here's an article](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/) I found explaining how to implement it in PHP.

Comment: But I think this is issue is only with chrome or with FireFox also.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both should block this POST request, though they may exhibit different symptoms when they block it. See the wikipedia article (first link) for browser compatibility with the CORS standard.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML 200 OK is not the same as a valid response.  It means the server got your request, but it doesn't mean that your PHP file actually returned usable data.  It could be returning an empty response altogether.  It's time to debug the PHP file.  I'd suggest logging to a file temporarily or use [FirePHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-php-firebug-firephp/).  If error display is disable (as it should be on a production server), this can happen if your script is failing before any output is generated.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is happening with the request? You can't make an ajax request cross-domain with what you have listed in the question.

However, you're sending an empty POST request to the URL, and when I replicate an empty post request, it responds with an HTTP 206 error, which is what you need to sort out.

`curl -X POST http://54.249.240.120/qcorner/login`

`{"head":{"status":206,"message":"Only 0 fields received, required 2"},"body":""}`

Comment: 206 isn't an error code. All 2xx codes mean the request was successful. 206 is a partial content response, in response to a request with a `Content-Range` header. I wonder why that's happening in this case.

Comment: I changed the return status to 200, still getting the same result, and this is not the http response, its just a string I am returning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and what I did is very simple.
In you PHP file receiving the ajax request, just add this line before sending the response :

```
<?php 
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
     ... // your code here
?>
```